# Compiler error: "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ;"

Tags: swift

I am getting an error after adding the bottom line of code in this screenshot.  Closing out and restarting Xcode did nothing and I really want to know what I'm doing wrong.

I apologize for asking what will probably be a simplistic question but I am new to coding with Swift.

I did have a problem importing CoreLocation as it did not auto populate like I thought it would.  It seems that problem might directly relate to this one.

[image: clipped screenshot of code]

Comment: Even though your question did elicit a response from the community, you could do two things to improve your future questions. 1.) never use images with your code; copy and paste your code instead 2.) make sure your question's formatting conforms to Stack Overflows [mcve]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not valid Swift syntax. The colon indicates the fact that you want to declare a variable/property, while the parentheses indicate that you want to create a new value, and values must be assigned via the equal character.

You should instead be writing

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

as Swift will infer the appropriate type if it can.

Or, if your want to also specify the type

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

or, if you want to simply declare it:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager
```

however, you'd better make it a `let` if you don't plan to change it:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

as `let` is always preferred in the first instance over `var`  - i.e. declare the variable as `let` and change it later to `var` if needed.

Comment: That did it.  I'm learning that following 'instructor led' classes on Udemy is not always accurate...even though I see them typing it without error on their video.  Thank you Cristik!